# Play Powerpoint presentation at correct resolution

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have created a Powerpoint 2010 presentation. I want to record this presentation with Camtasia to make a promotional video.

My presentation is exacly 640x360 pixels. When I edit the powerpoint and set zoom to 100%, it is displaying correct. However, there seems to be no way to play the presentation at exacly that resolution. I can run full screen or in windowed mode, but neither show it pixel perfect. In windowed mode I can stretch the window to the right resolution, but images still get pixelerated.

Anybody got a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powerpoint 2010 offers a save as a wmv file. Why not simply use that?

Comment: That is a good option. I can't find how to set the frame rate.

Comment: Edit: Just tried it. It look to have a framerate of 30, which is fine. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the pixelation you see is actually bad compression artifacts, not wrong resolution. Had similar problem with a presentation I made of some of my photo portfolio. I am interested too in finding how to control compression quality in PP.

Comment: I think it is not due to compression. In edit mode the images show perfect. But when playing the presentation they are slightly stretched (even by 1 pixel) which makes them look ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at this, and use the program recommended there instead of camtasia.

http://www.imtoo.com/convert-powerpoint-to-video/how-to-convert-ppt-to-avi-free.html

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't show the images at correct location and doesn't have the exact resolution I need.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you want to record a specific area that is much smaller than your full screen resolution, try recording with Camtasia Recorder instead of Camtasia's PowerPoint Add-in. That way you can select just the small area you'd like to record at the exact resolution  you want.